# is there an advantage in defining a method as static whenever possible in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style, static-methods

PyCharm gives me a hint `this method may be static`. Well, I know. But should I?

In C++ I would have defined a method static only if I had a good reason for that, mainly wanting to use the method not with any instance, or having a common data for all instances, like counters. What is the case in Python?

An answer I found says it saves memory, but I don't think the amount is such it should affect the coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a method doesn't interact with `self`, I'd make it `@staticmethod`. Especially for public APIs it's confusing if a method isn't static when it could be.

For example:

```
class File(object):
    BUFFERSIZE = 65536

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.descriptor = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_buffersize():
        return File.BUFFERSIZE

    def open(self, mode):
        self.descriptor = open(self.path, mode)

    def close(self):
        self.descriptor.close()
```

Obviously a stupid class but you get the idea, hopefully. In fact, in a real world application I'd make `get_buffersize` a `buffersize` property of `File`.